# OSGi Classloader not finding a class and not letting me include it

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

I am writing a plugin for a third-party OSGi container.  The plugin has code that looks something like this:

```
  Resource r=factory.getInstance().getResource("test");
  String s=r.getList()[0];
```

It fails on the second line with something like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:206)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thirdparty/list
        at user1.SampleCode.main(SampleCode.java:20)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thirdparty.list
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 42 more
```

Then, when I try to include the missing class into the plugin JAR, I get a different error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:206)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/thirdparty/list" 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at user1.SampleCode.main(SampleCode.java:20)
        ... 39 more
```

What is going on?  It appears that the classloader knows the class that I need and won't let me use it or even include my own copy of it.

Comment: The normal cause of this is when you have an exported package that depends on a private (i.e. bundle-internal) package. Is `com.thirdparty` present as a private package in more than one bundle? Can you please give more details e.g. the bundle contents and manifests.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.  You might be on to something, but I'm not sure how to answer your question.  There are a number of bundles that I've found, but `grep` shows up blank when searching for this particular class.  There are quite a few classes that do this, but most in this particular JAR are available.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Start with the content and manifest of the bundle that is throwing the exception.

Comment: It's my bundle throwing the exception, but the class I want to use is in a different bundle (installed by default in the container).  Do I need to set package visibility somehow on my own bundle?  Thanks again for your help.